# Modifying the Installshield scripts programmatically using scripts

Tags: vbscript, configuration-files, installshield, installscript

I'm new to Installshield. I need to customize an Installshield-8 project to my need.

Is there a possibility to set the IS Project information such as Product-Code, INSTALLDIR

and Product Version programmatically from an external application (probably using some

scripts)  Also,

Does using **InstallScript** in the Installshield-8 is of any help ?

My requirement is to be able to pass the configuration related information to a config

file and somehow read this information while compiling the Installshield-8 project

Any help in this direction is much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IS has a (version specific) COM [Automation Interface](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/IHelpAutomation.htm).  The [IswiProject](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield12helplib/IHelpAutoISWiProject.htm) object exposes INSTALLDIR, ProductCode and ProductVersion properties.  You can use this from a 32bit build process to transform the ISM before compiling.

Comment: As i see it, this is specific to the Installshield - 12. Any idea if this is available for Installshield 8

Comment: InstallShield (DevStudio) 8 or InstallShield 2008?

Comment: Christopher ... InstallShield(DevStudio) 8

Comment: I gotta be honest, you need an upgrade. DevStudio 8 is ancient and has many issues and lacking many features.

Comment: I know this is Christopher...but unfortunately its not in my hands.I have to find a solution using this version :(

Comment: First I got it wrong, it was called Developer 8... DevStudio was 9.  Eitherway, I can't remember if 8 could save in XML format or not or if it had an Automation Interface or not.  If it can only save in Binary then you can use MSI interop to query the tables and make updates.  FWIW, you shouldn't be using InstallScript at all in that version as it's design is simply broken and was fixed in v12.

Comment: The object is ISWiProject, not IswiProject.